# Domain is not pointing to my static ip address in aws lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-lightsail

Here are the steps I followed.

I purchased the domain in GoDaddy. I changed the name servers to point to lightsail.

In lightsail, I created a new DNS zone.
Created A record with @ pointing to the static ip address. 
Created A record with www pointing to the static ip address.

It's been more than 24 hours.

When I access the website with the static ip address, it works fine. But, when I access it from the domain name, I'm getting the below error.

example.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Double check if your four Lightsail Name servers are what you entered in Godady as your domain's name servers

Comment: may be sharing the actual domain might help in debugging it faster

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you deleted and recreated the domain under lightsail the NS records will change and you will need to update those with GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to access it over https you need to make sure you have opened port 443 in the Lightsail firewall - it is closed by default.

Find it under the networking tab of your Lightsail instance.

Comment: Possibly not directly related to the original question, but I had been trying to diagnose this for a while now and it turned out to fix my issue.  Thank you!